# Workspace Switcher icon is not valid in Mac Lion Theme

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, workspaces

In my Unity there is one problem:

[image: Workspace Switcher icon problem]

This issue hapened when I changed my icon theme to `Mac-Lion-Theme`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your icon theme doesn't have a dedicated icon for workspace-switcher. Hence, it is using a weird icon. We can possibly solve this problem by copying the default icon theme's icon for workspace-switcher and pasting it into your current icon theme.

Try the following command:

```
cp /usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/apps/48/workspace-switcher.png ~/.icons/Mac-Lion-Icons/apps/scalable
```

and

```
cp /usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/apps/48/workspace-switcher.png ~/.icons/Mac-Lion-Icons/apps/48/
```

Hopefully, that will solve your problem.